# Is registry cleaning effective?

Tags: windows-registry

Most so called experts would say online that registry cleaning speeds up your computer. I just found a handful opinions that say otherwise i.e. [Howtogeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/171633/why-using-a-registry-cleaner-wont-speed-up-your-pc-or-fix-crashes/)

Also there are some indirect answers here, but they are from like 4 years ago.

Would I be better off with not cleaning registry at all? Because benefits are dubious and the risk of messing it up is higher

Comment: I wouldn't clean my registry if I'm just looking to speed up my computer. I would do that if I was experiencing problems related to the registry, or if a virus messed up something. If you are experiencing performance issues, I would check other things first.

Comment: for the most part, cleaning your registery will do nothing to reduce the effort/time required for any particular atomic operation. There will be completely negligible effects from parsing a smaller file, or using slighly less ram to load them, but the registery is composed of tiny bits of information with a great deal of structure, so the size of the data is small both to load and parse, unless your system is so messed up that it won't boot anyway.

Comment: The article you linked to is accurate.

Comment: The links from the article are worth reading too

Comment: Be careful with these things; I ran one on Windows 8 and it didn't know about it, and it broke the Windows Store apps.  So they can cause more harm than good (if they do any good at all).

Comment: Really? An answer from 6 years ago is still valid state of the art? Nothing changed?

Comment: Well I doubt the way the Windows registry works has changed much at all. Sure there may be different keys but the registry isn't and hasn't been a big factor on speed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A registry cleaner will not fix crashes or problems of any kind because it only removes entries that it knows have no effect.

While a registry cleaner will have a very slight effect on performance, it's generally too small to measure. The registry is a fairly efficient structure, so reducing its size slightly won't make accesses measurably faster. And the time to detect that a file does not exist is pretty small too, so removing entries that lead to non-existent files won't save much time either.

That said, I'm one of those guys who likes a clean and tidy system. I defragment my drives because I enjoy it and I run a registry cleaner because junk offends me on a personal level.

Comment: "It's *almost* like snake oil, but I like snake oil because it makes everything really *shiny*." ^_^

Comment: I used to have the same mindset.  There was never a noticeable improvement, but I knew the registry was clean.  Then the registry cleaner made a few mistakes over time.  The work to diagnose the resulting problems cured me of this obsession.  The effects aren't always immediately apparent.

Comment: @David Schwartz  do not take registry garbage, software issues and hardware disk fragmentation as personal attack!! :)

Comment: Also aside from cleaning the registry, any contents it deletes that actually are needed will need to be recreated...

Comment: On many laptops from customers/friends, I consistently find that uninstalling junk programmes and using a good registry cleaner speeds up the laptop 1.5x-5x.

Comment: @toothbrush Certainly. It's kind of like in the matrix where the machines were powered by human bodies combined with a form of fusion.

Answer (score 4):

Not for performance. (You might shave a microsecond somewhere, but you've already wasted a million times that by clicking the Clean button.)

However, **if done properly**, it can resolve discrepancies in the system that confuse the user or other applications.

To give you a hypothetical example (I can't remember if this is exactly the sort of thing that can happen, but it's similar to the discrepancies I've seen happening and fixed), imagine uninstalling Photoshop and still seeing .PSD file types showing up as "Photoshop Document" but without any valid icon. This would indicate there are stale entries in the registry, where e.g. the description is present, but the file type handler is absent, and would leave the user wondering why the word Photoshop is still present even though the application has been already removed.
Similar things can leave other applications confused too, e.g. the handler might be present but the program it refers to might have been uninstalled, and hence it might no longer be possible to open the file.

So yes, they might be "effective" in some cases, and a Properly Written cleaning tool Should Not cause problems. But in practice, I wouldn't highly recommend them unless you're willing to examine what the tool is actually doing. The potential to break something further is too much to risk for the possibility of removing a user-visible discrepancy unless the user knows and limits what the tool is doing.

Answer (score 3):

**Literaly the answer is NO and YES but carefully and only with good justification.**

---

Oviously modifications or cleanup to the windows registry haves Advantages and Disadvantages.

Im personally against that Registry Cleanup Software which made a one touch registry clean task, without any noticeable warning, you always should keep in mind the scenario  where it is mandatory to touch the registry.

---

> **Scenarios:**

**Malware/Virus Infection**

Some viruses and malware, stores registry keys to reinforce the infection. you should use some anti malware software feature to remove that malicious keys from you registry and in that scenario the Registry modifications are justified.

**Registry Damage/Registry Corruption:**

If you experience Registry Corruption or Registry Damage you could use an especific tool to recover your lost registry keys from a previous backup.

There are only 2 scenarios only as example, but could be many more.

---

And be carefull using Registry Tweakers only because you was warned by an ad or by a mail or for amateur forum, it could be only a trick to infect your system, there are some [Scareware](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scareware) just to made some scamm to good people.

---

Only using Registry Cleaner to remove unused keys or orphan registry keys maybe will Boost the Start-up cause registry will be smaller and will take less time to be loaded.

Comment: If you have to muck about in the registry to clean up malware, you're probably better off re-paving the system.

Comment: Absolutly right, it could be an option too, some people prefer come back to the beginning with a fresh install, some people are fighters and want to learn trying to fight versus the system, but idk, both options are valid and respectables.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia: I find Windows so poorly documented (compared to GNU/Linux) that you hardly ever learn anything while solving a problem that you can apply to any other problem.  I'm not a big fan of re-installs, because I like having stuff configured just the way I like it.  Blowing that all away with a reinstall means a huge amount of work.

Comment: You are right, but that is because Windows sells support and it is oriented to be used by all kind of users not only superusers